# Why did Reese go to Hell?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, lucifer

It's confusing, why did Reese go to hell in Lucifer S03E07, while he did good? It's not like he killed somebody: he was trying to expose Lucifer about being the devil, and wanted to create a story that would destroy Lucifer (but eventually he can't get any leads). And he does not want to break up with Linda because he still loves her. What is Reese's sin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Reese went to Hell because *he* felt he deserved it.

It's not an issue of Good or Bad but *guilt*.

As Lucifer explained to Reese...

> L: I have a story for you, reporter. One I've never told a human soul before. I take no part in who goes to Hell.
>
> R: Then who does?
>
> L: You humans. [CHUCKLES] You send yourselves. Driven down by your own guilt. Forcing yourselves to relive your sins over and over.
>
> And the best part the doors aren't locked.You could leave anytime. It says something that no one ever does, doesn't it?
>
> R: No. You're to blame.
>
> L: I am responsible for a lot of things, Reese, but not your soul, not your actions, and not whoever killed that poor girl downstairs.

Essentially, Reese felt guilty for trying to get Alvin to kill Lucifer, causing the accidental death and not being willing to accept that his marriage to Linda was over.

Comment: That's a lousy rule.  It means that people like Genghis Khan, Tamarlane, Hitler, Stalin, and Mao are likely to go to heaven because they feel that they are good and deserve heaven, while great humanitarians, public benefactors, life savers, and philanthropists are likely to go to hell because they are haunted by guilt thinking about all the good that they failed to do and the lives they failed to save.

Comment: @M.A.Golding  -they are - i.e. Kain says he will go to heaven even while being a multiple murderer because he doesn't regret anything. But in the Lucifer universe, God and angels also aren't particularly nice

Comment: @M.A.Golding you have to remember that this rule exist in realm where Hitler was killed to stop a Nazi super-weapon - vampiric octopuses.

Answer (score 4):

Just like @Paulie_D explained, it is a matter of feeling guilt.

However, it was a little bit more complicated in the original comic: it wasn't as much just a **sense of guilt**, but a sense that **you need to be punished for your sins**. If you felt that you should be punished for your "sins", you were punished, in a way more drastic than displayed in the show. This in a way, was turning hell into a heaven for masochists...

Just for a note: there were other ways to get to Hell: you could be sent there by a powerful entity (like a [Dream of the Endless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dream_(character))) or by selling your soul to any of the demons. Also, there were more than one hells - in the comic Lucifer goes to the Asian hell, where the sinners are being tortured with nightmares of the living.

Comment: Here's a page from vol. IV of _The Sandman_, "Season of Mists", which would illustrate your point: https://elixi.re/i/rjf63p5i.png